# MIstake in jquery (mby ror)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this error when i open console in browser.

> TypeError: Constructor Document requires 'new'

A bit of code

```
$("#profile_info").click(function() {
    console.log("works");
});
```

I'm using RoR jquery gem, so could be problem in it?

Comment: The code you show is not related to that error, I bet there's more javascript on your code. On the browser, the console should point to a file an line and actual code that triggers that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided isn't the issue. Based on the error you are probably using the constructor Document somewhere in your code but you should be using the document object for example:

```
$(Document).ready(function(){})
```

should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```